# Iterate through text node and element node

Tags: javascript, children, nodechildren

I used element.children to iterate through element nodes and childNodes for text node.
How can I iterate both text node and element node?

```
let children = this.element.children;
for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  // do something with children[i] element
}
let childrenNodes = this.element.childNodes;
for (let i = 0; i < childrenNodes.length; i++) {
  if (childrenNodes[i].nodeName == "#text") {
    // do something with childrenNodes[i] text node
  }
}
```

Can I access to an element with childNodes?

Comment: Please post some code (current HTML/JS etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes), which contains both element and text nodes:

```
const childNodes = this.element.childNodes;
for (let i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
  if (childNodes[i].nodeType == 1) {
    // do something with childrenNodes[i] element
  } else if (childNodes[i].nodeType == 3) {
    // do something with childrenNodes[i] text node
  }
}
```

You should distinguish them by the [`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType), not by the `nodeName`.

Comment: If I have a node element (finded with 'childNodes[i].nodeType == 3'), how can I have a reference to the element?
If I write console.log(childNodes[i]) I have <!---->

Comment: @asv That should not happen, a comment node has `nodeType` 8. Can you make a [mcve] that demonstrates this problem?